# modify Observable in Angular and return new Observable with made changes

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have a this Observable

`obs1$ = this.otherService.getObservable()` which is of type number

I want to create a method which emits a Observable using the return value of this Observable

```
 combined() {
    this.currentLambdaReactorState$.subscribe((e) => {
      let dto = of([
        {
          name: 'foo',
          value: e,
        },
      ])
        return dto
    });
  }
```

so far this method does not return anything, how can I return a Observable from that method ?

Comment: That is what the map operator is for I guess..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map is what you want here.

```
// replace any with your type (returned from currentLambdaReactorState$)
combined(): Observable<{name: string, value: any}> {
  return this.currentLambdaReactorState$.pipe(
    // shorthand object literal return
    map((e)=> ({name: 'foo', value: e})) 
  )
}

// usage
combined().subscribe((mappedValue) => {
  console.log(mappedValue); // {name: 'foo', value: e}
});
```